# How can medieval knights fend off against army of radioactive ghouls?

Tags: medieval, military-defense, zombies, radiation

On the night of November 27, 1419 somewhere near a river bank the water glows bright blue. It was due to a phenomenon known as Cherenkov radiation which was unheard of back then, all these high energy charged particles were emitted from the body of thousands of ghouls as they swam out from the water and slowly marched inland. Despite not carrying any protective gears or armed with anything, the amount of radioaction at close proximity is equivalent to 100 CT scans! Do not wrestle them because surviving reports told of their immeasurable strength and ability to leap tall tower in a single bound, is there any hope for the medieval knights against such a formidable foe? The ghoul's IQ is about 90 give and take using today standard, they don't feel any sensation but can still bleed out and become incapacitated.

Comment: That's an extremely vague question. What do you mean by fight ? Like effectively kill ? Do the ghouls have any special properties (except for strength and radioactivity) that might have an influence on how to kill them ?
Because unless you have more specifics then the answer is pretty much this : just kill them like you would a human, it's just more of a challenge.

Comment: whose IQ ? the knights or the ghouls ?

Comment: @Kaloyan: objective is try to fend off like incapacitate the enemy

Comment: are this ghoul can die from any wound or like zombie that can only die from losing their head ?

Comment: @Li Jun: I'm referring to the ghoul.

Comment: so far i can only think about using fire tactic or trap, and dig moat full of pike inside the castle or use pike formation like phalanx to prevent them from jumping, since as far as i understand (iam not good with english so maybe i was wrong hence i put it here) you only describe how tall they can jump but not how far they can jump, outside of using range weapon like sling, crossbow,bow, even catapult or trebuchet.

Comment: Persons, this would include radioactive ghouls, with an IQ of 90, would be functionally in terms of intelligence, normal. They're not dullards or idiots.

Comment: So basically a Mary Sue version of ghouls. Feels like a trick question honestly. There isn't a way to defeat them if they are that strong and also intelligent (intelligent in the sense of intellectually apt, not in the sense of genius). The knights would just die or run off. I don't see what would prevent the ghouls from using weapons and armor too. The invicibility of these ghouls kind of negate the point of the question in the first place

Comment: @a4android: I need them to at least to navigate the environment and to overcome common barriers.

Comment: With an IQ of 90 they will be able to do that easily. In fact, as well as any ordinary person could.

Answer (score 1):

Castles are pretty much useless if they can just jump over the walls, so you will have to fight them on an open field, it really depends on how you gonna get a large enough force to fight them. 
Weapons like longbows, polearms and early versions of muscets might be the weapons you wanna go for to stay away from them as far as possible, although polearms will become useless depending on how fast they are (i assume they are since they can jump the hight of a tower). 
Here are some other important things you need to tell us to become more accurate with an answer:
Can they feel pain? How much arrows does it take to stop them? (Can you cripple them? If so you might wanna use caltrops too) Will they even risk an open battle when they are not that dumb?

Comment: No they are immune to any sensation, simply impale them isn't going to stop them in their track you need to incapacitate them

Comment: Well, no weapon i mentioned will be very useful then, arrows and projectiles wont kill them efficiently enough (assuming they attack in packs/an army) and polearms are likely to miss due to their speed, although theyd easily incapacitate them with a single (not too terrible) hit.

Answer (score 1):

> It was due to a phenomenon known as Cherenkov radiation

Cherenkov radiation occurs when a particle travels faster than the speed of light in a given medium. Given air's low density and low refractive index, a particle needs to be travelling at about 0.9997c in order to produce the glow you want. Alpha particles won't travel far enough through air to give you the glow you need, beta particles travelling that fast are too energetic for fission or fusion reactions (let alone plain old radioactive decay) and neutrons going that fast will be almost impossible to generate by any means.

What you've got, then, is merely [ionised air glow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionized-air_glow). Don't worry, it still looks as nice.

(incidentally, if they *did* generate actual Cherenkov radiation, everything around them would just die. forget "100CT scans", whatever that means, think more "active unshielded nuclear reactor in your face")

> the amount of radioaction at close proximity is equivalent to 100 CT scans!

"100CT scans" is a *very* ill-defined amount of radiation, but lets imagine that a knight trying to fight them receives an an entire [Sievert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert). That's enough to cause radiation sickness, but not necessarily enough to kill them

Anyway... chances are, no-one will know. Either they'll see the mystical halos, and run away, or they'll see the ghoul's terrifying strength, and run away, or they'll get splatted by a ghoul. That dose of radiation is high, but not enough to incapacitate promptly. They'll get sick later but won't necessarily die (though regular illness or infection will have a good chance of finishing them off).

> Do not wrestle them because surviving reports told of their immeasurable strength and ability to leap tall tower in a single bound, is there any hope for the medieval knights against such a formidable foe?

You haven't said what will kill or incapacitate the ghouls. Maybe they're vulnerable to harsh language?

If arrow-fire can't stop them, then there's nothing to do but get out of their way. Given their leaping ability and mighty strength, they can't really be trapped, or blocked. The radiation is almost entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Incapacitate them is good enough

Answer (score 0):

A high wall with a field of pointed stakes on the other side should be enough to deal with them, as they are too dumb to spot the trap.

Lured into leaping over the wall and impaling themselves (and then being bombarded with stones and arrows) , they all die with zero casualties.

Comment: 90 IQ isn't too dumb to spot the trap